# Difficulties in removing characters and white space to tokenize text via Spacy

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I'm testing the Spacy library, but I'm having trouble cleaning up the sentences (ie removing special characters; punctuation; patterns like [Verse], [Chorus], \n ...) before working with the library.

I have removed, to some extent, these elements, however, when I perform the tokenization, I notice that there are extra white spaces, in addition to the separation of terms like "it" and "s" (it's).

Here is my code with some text examples:

```
text1 = "[Intro] Well, alright [Chorus] Well, it's 1969, okay? All across the USA It's another year for me and you"
text2 = "[Verse 1] For fifty years they've been married And they can't wait for their fifty-first to roll around"
text3 = "Passion that shouts And red with anger I lost myself Through alleys of mysteries I went up and down Like a demented train"
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':[text1, text2, text3]})
```

```
replacer ={'\n':' ',"[\[].*?[\]]": " ",'[!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~1234567890’”“′‘\\\]':" "}
df['cleanText'] = df['text'].replace(replacer, regex=True)
df.head()
```

```
df['new_col'] = df['cleanText'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
df
```

```
#Output:
result1 = "  Well  alright   Well  it s       okay  All across the USA It s another year for me and you"
result2 = "  For fifty years they ve been married And they can t wait for their fifty first to roll around"
result3 = "Passion that shouts And red with anger I lost myself Through alleys of mysteries I went up and down Like a demented train"
```

When I try to tokenize, I get, for example: (  , Well,  , alright,   , Well,  , it, s,    ...)

I used the same logic to remove the characters to tokenize via nltk and there it worked. Does anyone know what I might be wrong?

Comment: Note that you don't need to do this cleaning before you pass text to spaCy. In fact you shouldn't remove the punctuation, and I suspect it'd be easier to remove the bracketed text by using spaCy's tokenizer, filtering the text, and then passing the filtered text to spaCy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex pattern removes almost all extra *white spaces* since I change the sentences `" "` by `""` and finally add `' +':' '` like this

```
replacer = {'\n':'',"[\[].*?[\]]": "",'[!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~1234567890’""′‘\\\]':"", ' +': ' '}
```

then after applying the regex pattern, call `strip()` method to remove white spaces at begin and end.

```
df['cleanText'] = df['cleanText'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```

and when you define the *column* `new_col` using `npl()`:

```
df['new_col'] = df['cleanText'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
```

```
[3 rows x 3 columns]
>>> df
                                                text                                          cleanText                                            new_col
0  [Intro] Well, alright [Chorus] Well, it's 1969...  Well alright Well its okay All across the USA ...  (Well, alright, Well, its, okay, All, across, ...
1  [Verse 1] For fifty years they've been married...  For fifty years theyve been married And they c...  (For, fifty, years, they, ve, been, married, A...
2  Passion that shouts And red with anger I lost ...  Passion that shouts And red with anger I lost ...  (Passion, that, shouts, And, red, with, anger,...
```